# Eigenvalues of f(A), when A is not diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

Howdy just a simple question,

I know when A is diagonalizable, the eigenvalues of F(A) are just simply $F(\lambda_i)$ where $\lambda_i \exists \sigma (A)$

I'm interested in the case of when A is not diagonalizable. I look at A as a Jordan form, but I cannot seem to show that when $A$ is not diagonalizable, that the eigenvalues of F(A) are $F(\lambda_i$). I'm okay with no proof, just want to know if the eigenvalues of F(A) are $F(\lambda_i$) when A is not diagonalizable.

Comment: How do you define $f(A)$ when $A$ is not diagonalizable?

Comment: What kind of function is $F$?

Comment: Analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $F$ is a polynomial, it's true even when $A$ is not diagonalizable and the proof is the same. If $v$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ and if $F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^p a_k x^k$, then

$$F(A)v = \sum_{k=1}^p a_k A^k v  = \sum_{k=1}^p a_k \lambda^k v = F(\lambda)v.$$

Comment: This only proves that $F(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue, not that all eigenvalues have this form.

Comment: Yes, I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe $F$ is a polynomial, $F(t)=b_0+b_1t+\dots+b_nt^n$, so
$$
F(A)=b_0I+b_1A+\dots+b_nA^n
$$
You can assume $A$ is in Jordan canonical form, which is triangular. The eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are the coefficients on the diagonal and, for a triangular matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$, the coefficient at place $(i,i)$ in $F(A)$ is $F(a_{ii})$.